# Interleaving values from several iterables

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, iterator

I am new to Python and am trying to see if there is a cleaner way to write my code. The following code take iterables as parameter it produces the first value from the first parameter, then the first value from the the second parameter, ..., then the first value from the last parameter; then the second value from the first parameter and so on.If any iteratable produces no more values, this generator produces no more values.

If I do:

```
for i in skip('abcde','fg','hijk'):
  print(i,end='')
```

produces the values 'a', 'f', 'h', 'b', 'g', 'i', and 'c'. The code I've written is as under(which works):

```
def skip(*args):
  itrs = [iter(arg) for arg in args]
  while itrs != []: 
     temp = [] 
     for i in range(len(itrs)): 
        try: 
          yield next(itrs[i]) 
          temp.append(itrs[i]) 
        except StopIteration: 
          pass
      itrs = temp
```

Is there a cleaner/ concise way to write the code(without using any external libraries)?

Comment: The code given does not stop at `c`, it produces `afhbgicjdke`. I think you meant to `return` instead of `pass` in the except block

Comment: The function, as written (but not as specified), is similar to the built-in [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), but with no fill values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I think there is an error in the original code. The code produces `afhbgicjdke` instead of the expected `afhbgic`. I think the intention was to `return` instead of `pass` in the stop iteration block, the answer below work under this assumption.

Let's look at the for loop in the middle

```
for i in range(len(itrs)):
    try:
        yield next(itrs[i])
        temp.append(itrs[i])
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

No where in the body operate on the index, so every `itrs[i]` can be replaced with just `i` with a simpler `for i in iters`. This gives us

```
for i in itrs:
    try:
        yield next(i)
        temp.append(i)
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

Now lets look at the `while` body

```
while itrs != []:
    temp = []
    # ... the for loop that includes an append to itrs
    itrs = temp
```

This basically gives the code a way to exit when everything is finished. However, if you think about how the code works, the only time `itrs` has a lower length than `args` is when one of the itrs reaches `StopIteration`. In that case, we would have returned already!

So the while loop can become a while True loop and `temp` and it's usage can be ommited.

```
def skip(*args):
    itrs = [iter(arg) for arg in args]
    while True:
        for i in itrs:
            try:
                yield next(i)
            except StopIteration:
                return
```

Now we need to convince ourselves that the code will actually return at some point. This isn't too hard, as long as one of the iterable passed in is finite i.e. has an end, we will reach `StopIteration` at some point. And in the case that every iterable is infinite, the original code would run forever too. So we are good there.

But there is another problem. What if `skip` is called with no argument? This will result in us never returning from the function, since there is no iterable for us to trigger `StopIteration`! In the original code, this is dealt with implicitly through `temp` being empty. Since we don't have that anymore, we have to handle it explicitly.
This gives us the final code:

```
def skip(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return
    itrs = [iter(arg) for arg in args]
    while True:
        for i in itrs:
            try:
                yield next(i)
            except StopIteration:
                return
```

With this

```
for i in skip('abcde','fg','hijk'):
    print(i,end='')
```

outputs `afhbgic` and

```
for i in skip():
    print(i,end='')
```

is a noop

As an aside, the indentation in the original code is inconsistent, which makes it un-runnable. Please be sure to post usable code next time

Answer (score 5):

You said about not using external libraries, but if it's OK for you to use the Python standard library, you can pretty much do what you want with `cycle` function from `itertools` used on an iterable of iterators:

```
from itertools import cycle

def skip(*args):
    return (next(i) for i in cycle(iter(arg) for arg in args))
```

or a more condensed version for Python 3:

```
from itertools import cycle

def skip(*args):
    return map(next, cycle(map(iter, args)))
```

The same more condensed version for Python 2:

```
from itertools import cycle, imap

def skip(*args):
    return imap(next, cycle(imap(iter, args)))
```

In any case you don't need to catch `StopIteration` in Python 2 inside generator: throwing it ends the generator automatically and is caught by the caller. So even without `itertools` you can do something like this:

```
def skip(*args):
    if not args:
        return
    iters = [iter(arg) for arg in args]
    while True:
        for it in iters:
            yield next(it)
```

As per comment by @XrXrXr the solution with `cycle` due to deprecation of bubbling of `StopIteration` in Python 3.5 would become:

```
def skip(*args):
    try:
        yield from (next(i) for i in cycle(iter(arg) for arg in args))
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

Comment: Note that this behavior of `StopIteration` is going to be deprecated starting 3.5. See [PEP479](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)